# Extracting schema from a mongoose schema file

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to extract schema from a mongoose schema file but the imported object is always null.
I know there are even libraries for extracting schema from mongoDB but I'm trying to extract it from mongoose file.

Below is what I've tried.

```
// App.js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import productSchema from "./models/product";

export default function App() {
  console.log(productSchema.schema);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{productSchema.schema}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

```
// product.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  color: String,
  material: String,
  brandName: String,
  logo: String,
  dimensions: String,
  weight: String,
  battery: String,
  price: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

I'm getting `Cannot read property 'schema' of null` because productSchema is null.

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mongooseform-c26vb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Mongoose in the browser and according to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html):

> Mongoose's browser library does not support saving documents, queries, populate, discriminators, or any other Mongoose feature other than schemas and validating documents.

I think that's why the call to the `model` function returns null. You can have both schema and model in separate files and include whatever you need.

**App.js**

```
import productSchema from "./models/product-schema";

export default function App() {
  console.log('Schema: ', productSchema);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**./models/product-schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  color: String,
  material: String,
  brandName: String,
  logo: String,
  dimensions: String,
  weight: String,
  battery: String,
  price: Number
});

module.exports = productSchema;
```

**./models/product**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const productSchema = require("./product-schema");

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

See the updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mongooseform-s3moh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark